# How can I see attributes on a python namedlist object?

Tags: python, inspect

I have been using namedlist to create lightweight classes:

```
from namedlist import namedlist
# create a class
SomeClass = namedlist('SomeClass', 'foo bar', use_slots=False)

# create an object
my_list = SomeClass(1,2)

# set an attribute not specified in the class
my_list.baz = 3

# the attribute is there if I reference it
print(my_list.baz)
# output: 3
```

Sometimes I want to take an object and see if any extra attributes have been set:

```
# this doesn't show 'baz'
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(my_list)

# neither does this
my_list.__dict__
```

Is there a way I can see any attributes that have been added in this way?

Comment: The attributes haven't been added, just [**`__getattr__`**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) has been overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of `namedlist`, we can see that the factory function `namedlist()`, generates the type (`SomeClass` in your example).

Now this is interesting.

On one hand, `__getattribute__` and `__setattribute__` were not overloaded, which lets you do things like `my_list.baz = 3` and then access it as `my_list.baz`.

On the other, `__dict__`, was overridden with `property(_asdict)` (generated in `_common_fields()`). This causes whoever uses `__dict__` to fail seeing `baz` - function such as `dir()` and the `inspect` module.

While I failed to find a function that will list the added attributes in this case, if you know what attribute you are looking for, you can still check if it exists using `hasattr(my_list, 'baz')`:

```
>>> from namedlist import namedlist
>>> SomeClass = namedlist('SomeClass', 'foo bar', use_slots=False)
>>> my_list = SomeClass(1,2)
>>> my_list.baz = 3
>>> hasattr(my_list, 'baz')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If switching types is going to be problematic (maybe there is legacy code already using namedlist), I found that the following makes viewing `namedlist` bearable:

```
def set_attr(self, attr_name, attr_val):
        setattr(self, attr_name, attr_val)
        self.opt_attrs.append(attr_name)

    TypeA = namedlist('TypeA', 'field_a opt_attrs', use_slots=False)
    TypeA.set_attr = set_attr

    TypeB = namedlist('TypeB', 'field_b opt_attrs', use_slots=False)
    TypeB.set_attr = set_attr

    objA = TypeA(1, [])
    objA.set_attr('field_x', 2)

    objB = TypeB(7, [])

objA
# Out: TypeA(field_a=1, opt_attrs=['field_x'])

objA.field_x
# Out: 2

objB
# Out: TypeB(field_b=7, opt_attrs=[])
```

It is probably best to just to use python classes though.  More up-front code, less after-the-fact confusion:

```
class TypeA:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A(a={})".format(self.a)

class TypeB:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return "B(b={})".format(self.b)

A = TypeA(1)
A.x = 2

B = TypeB(7)

class TypeA:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A(a={})".format(self.a)

class TypeB:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return "B(b={})".format(self.b)

objA = TypeA(1)
objA.x = 2

objB = TypeB(7)

objA
# Out: A(a=1)

objA.__dict__
# Out: {'a': 1, 'x': 2}

objB
# Out: B(b=7)
```